# Change video language in php

Tags: php

I am working on a project, a web site for playing movies.
I'm having trouble setting the language of the video, in case some films are dual audio.
How can I do this procedure? I want to leave the video language in PT-BR.
I made the PHP script below, but it doesn't work, thank you to anyone who can help, thanks.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var streamsrc = "<?php echo IP; ?>/<?php echo $tipo; ?>/<?php echo $user; ?>/<?php echo $pwd; ?>/<?php echo $id; ?>.<?php echo $exts; ?>";
  var playerobj = window.playerobj = videojs("livevideo", {sources: {type: "video/mp4", src: streamsrc}, controls: true, autoplay: true, loop: false, language: "pt-br", languages: {pt-br: {LIVE: "AO VIVO", Fullscreen: "Tela inteira", Pause: "Pausar", Play: "Reproduzir", Mute: "Mudo", Unmute: "Ativar som"}}, notSupportedMessage: "Ops, algo saiu errado.", preload: "none", muted: false, controlBar: { fullscreenToggle: false, volumePanel: false }, plugins: { airplayButton: {} }});
  playerobj.on('ended', function() { go('filmes.php?sessao=<?php echo $_GET['sessao']; ?>&id=<?php echo $idcategoria; ?>'); });
 </script>
 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your JavaScript is breaking here: `languages: {pt-br: {LIVE...` The problem is the hyphen in the key. I can't test your exact code, but try this instead: `languages: {"pt-br": {LIVE...`

Comment: Without success, I made the change but the film is still in another language

Comment: Can you help me? i am willing to pay for it